# AutoMapper condition Mapping Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper, ef-core-3.1

I have got a problem using Automapper when conditionally Mapping a table.

**Here is an example:**

```
public class DepositsVm : IMapFrom<Deposits>
    {
        public long DepId { get; set; }
        public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
        public void Mapping(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.CreateMap<Deposits, DepositsVm>()
                .ForMember(d => d.DepId, s => s.MapFrom(s => s.DepId))
                .ForMember(d => d.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ProcessingId != null ? s.DataProcessing.GridCollect.Grid.Address : s.Reduction.DataCollect.Tower.Address));
        }
    }
```

*This results in an Object reference error.*

I can see we can use https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions but this allow to check for only one condition. I expect to map a table using different join condition in failure and success scenarios.

But this works, because I'm projecting each Address separately. But, this is not desired. Because both are from Same Address Table

```
public class DepositsVm : IMapFrom<Deposits>
{
    public long DepId { get; set; }
    public AddressDto GridAddress { get; set; }
    public AddressDto TowerAddress { get; set; }
    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
    {
        profile.CreateMap<Deposits, DepositsVm>()
            .ForMember(d => d.DepId, s => s.MapFrom(s => s.DepId))
            .ForMember(d => d.GridAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DataProcessing.GridCollect.Grid.Address));
    .ForMember(d => d.TowerAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Reduction.DataCollect.Tower.Address));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either some part of `s.DataProcessing.GridCollect.Grid.Address` is null, or some part of `s.Reduction.DataCollect.Tower.Address` is null

Comment: No, The chain will always have data. Even i tried for a single row, It failed. Somehow  automapper doesn't allow this mapping. If I do it separately (just updated the question), It works, Separate address may not help.

Comment: If its working separately, make sure AddressDto, Grid.Address and Tower.Address have same property names.